# Integral involving $\log(x+a)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I'm interested in the following integral:

$$\int_m^\infty\log(x+a) (1 + z(x-m))^{(-1-1/z)}dx$$

with $a>0$ and $m>0$ and $z\neq0$. All standard methods seem to fail here - is there anything to try? Was also playing around with differentiating under the integral sign (without introducing a new parameter but using the already existing $a$ - but got also stuck (as the differentiated integral $\frac{(1 + z(x-m))^{(-1-1/z)}}{x+a}$ does not become easier to solve).

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Pretty $z$ must also be greater than zero for the integral to converge, not merely nonzero.

Comment: Clearly true, so lets specify z>0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the improper integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a,m,z\right)}:=\int_{m}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[1+z(x-m)\right]^{-1-1/z}\ln{\left(a+x\right)}.$$

---

Suppose $\left(a,m,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{3}$, and set $a+m=:p>0\land\frac{1}{z}=:q>0$, followed by $\frac{q}{p}=:r>0$. After the appropriate shifting and scaling, we can obtain a much more compact expression for the integral $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of these auxiliary parameters:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,m,z\right)}
&=\int_{m}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[1+z(x-m)\right]^{-1-1/z}\ln{\left(a+x\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\left(1+zy\right)^{-1-1/z}\ln{\left(a+m+y\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=m+y\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\left(1+q^{-1}y\right)^{-1-q}\ln{\left(p+y\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,q\left(1+t\right)^{-1-q}\ln{\left(p+qt\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=qt\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\left[\ln{\left(p\right)}+\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}\right]\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{(-1)}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}\left[\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(-1)}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(-1)}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}\left[0-(-1)\right]+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Given fixed but arbitrary $(q,r)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}$, consider the following derivative w.r.t. $t$ on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]
&=\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\frac{d}{dt}\left[\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}\right]+\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]\\
&=\frac{r}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(1+rt\right)}-q\left(1+t\right)^{-1-q}\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}-\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}.\\
\end{align}$$

L'Hôpital's rule can be used to evaluate the following limit:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(1+t\right)^{q}\right]}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{r}{1+rt}\right)}{q\left(1+t\right)^{q-1}}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\frac{r\left(1+t\right)}{1+rt}\cdot\frac{1}{q\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\frac{1+t}{r^{-1}+t}\cdot\frac{q^{-1}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]\\
&=\left[\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1+t}{r^{-1}+t}\right]\cdot\left[\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{q^{-1}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right]\\
&=1\cdot0\\
&=0.\\
\end{align}$$

We then find

$$\implies\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}-\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right],$$

$$\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}-\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}\right],$$

$$\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}-\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\right]=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}}-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}},$$

$$\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}-\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\right]=0,$$

$$\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}.$$

Recall that for any $\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\xi\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $0<\beta<\gamma\land\xi<1$, the following improper integral converges and can be expressed in terms of the Gauss hypergeometric function:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{\gamma-\beta-1}\left(1+t\right)^{\alpha-\gamma}}{\left(1-\xi+t\right)^{\alpha}}=\operatorname{B}{\left(\beta,\gamma-\beta\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;\xi\right)}.$$

It follows from the integration formula above that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)^{-q}}{\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}=q^{-1}{_2F_1}{\left(1,q;q+1;1-r^{-1}\right)};~~~\small{0<q\land0<r}.$$

Returning now to the evaluation of $\mathcal{I}$, we finally obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,m,z\right)}
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{q\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{\left(1+t\right)^{1+q}}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)^{q}\left(r^{-1}+t\right)}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}+q^{-1}{_2F_1}{\left(1,q;q+1;1-r^{-1}\right)}\\
&=\ln{\left(p\right)}+q^{-1}{_2F_1}{\left(1,q;q+1;1-\frac{p}{q}\right)}\\
&=\ln{\left(a+m\right)}+z\,{_2F_1}{\left(1,z^{-1};z^{-1}+1;1-(a+m)z\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---